# How can I get an XPath expression that identifies a node in Java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I have an XML document with the following structure:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <bd>
            <cd>
                <aa/>
                <bb/>
                <aa/>
            </cd>
        </bd>
    </a>
    <a>
        <bd>
            <cd>
                <aa/>
                <bb/>
                <aa/>
            </cd>
        </bd>
    </a>
    <tt>
        <at/>
        <bt/>
    </tt>
</root>
```

I am using a recursive function which takes a node object as a parameter. I want to get the xpath of each node in an indexed XPath expression, like `root/a[1]/bd[0]/aa[2]`. I am using DOM parser and calling this function from another recursive function.

```
private static String getXPath(Node test_tempNode) {
    if (test_tempNode == null
            || test_tempNode.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        return "";
    }

    return getXPath(test_tempNode.getParentNode()) + "/"
            + test_tempNode.getNodeName();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like XML to me - presumably the tags like `<root/>` are supposed to be `</root>`.  Please edit the question and fix the XML to be well-formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work except it doesn't add the index; So I suppose all you have to do is to search the position of the current node in its parent child list and add that to xpath

```
private static String getXPath(Node test_tempNode) {
    if (test_tempNode == null
            || test_tempNode.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        return "";
    }

    //find index of the test_tempNode node in parent "list"
    Node parent = test_tempNode.getParentNode();
    NodeList childNodes = parent.getChildNodes();
    int index = 0;
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node current = childNodes.item(i);
        if (current.getNodeName().equals(test_tempNode.getNodeName())) {
            if (current == test_tempNode) {
                found = index;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }

    String strIdx = "[" + found + "]";
    if(index == 1){
        strIdx = "";
    }
    return getXPath(test_tempNode.getParentNode()) + "/"
            + test_tempNode.getNodeName() + strIdx;
}
```

Comment: But this will add index to those nodes too, which are not repeating....
We have to add index to only those nodes which are repeating

**Thanks for the help** i am trying to modify it and please keep me posted if you got it first.. Thanks Again

Comment: Thanks alot Sir... This piece of code is really helpful

Comment: The `found` value should not be always greater than `0`? If that's true then you should increment the `index` value before assigning it to `found`

Answer (score 0):

This should print out a unique path for each node, adding index as necessary.

```
private void printXPaths(Node node, OutputStream stream, String current, Map<String, int> occurences)
{
    if (node.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        return;
    }
    String nodePath = current + "/" + node.getNodeName();
    if(occurences.contains(nodePath)) {
        int occurrencesCount = occurences[nodePath];
        nodePath += "[" + occurrencesCount + "]";
        occurences[nodePath] = occurrencesCount + 1;
    } else {
        occurences[nodePath] = 1;
    }

    stream.println(nodePath);
    NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
    for(int i=0; i<children.getLength(); i++) {
        printXPaths(children.item(i), stream, nodePath, occurences);
    }
}

public void printXPaths(Document doc, OutputStream stream) {
    printXPaths(doc.getDocumentElement(), stream, "", new HashMap<String, int>());
}
```

In this way, the first indication will show /root/tag, while the second will show /root/tag[1] and so forth.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I am not able to get the index in the xpath by this.. not working in my scenario. output should be like root/a[1]/bd[1]/aa[2] for each node index should be there if it is repeating. 
Thanks